# Update only blank rows with Appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Question about updating blank rows. Below I have a query that works to update all cells in column A, however I need to change it to update only blank cells. Right now the query below will update all cells in column B that contain a value in column A. The problem is that this overwrites all cells column B instead of just the blank cells.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to include an `If` statement into this query so it will only update the cells in column B that are blank instead of the full column.

```
function fillFormulae(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  var lastUsedRow = sheets.getLastRow();
  var arrayOfFormulae = new Array(lastUsedRow - 2);       

  for (j=0; j < lastUsedRow - 2; j ++ ){
    arrayOfFormulae[j] = [Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PST", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")];
  }

  sheets.getRange(3, 2, (lastUsedRow - 2), 1).setValues(arrayOfFormulae);  
}
```

Thanks!

Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an array, I would do it one cell at a time.

```
function fillFormulae(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  var lastUsedRow = sheets.getLastRow();

  for (j=0; j < lastUsedRow - 2; j ++ ){
    var cell = sheets.getRange(3+j, 2);
    if (cell.getValue() == '') {
      cell.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PST", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick! Good idea on dropping the array. Thanks, Fabricator :)